# Extract all nodes of a node in an XML file by Pugixml C++

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, pugixml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<Employee>
    <Address>
        <Name>XYZ</CustomerName>
        <Street>street no. 1</Street>
        <City>current city</City>
        <Country>country</Country>
    </Address>
</Employee>
```

I want to extract the values of all the nodes of the node `Address` and want to store the values in a String Vector (i.e. `std::vector<std::string> EmployeeAdressDetails`).

***How can I extract the nodes in a loop instead of extracting values one by one?***

**UPDATE:** By"Extracting one by one", I mean something like following:

```
xml_node root_node = doc.child("Employee");
xml_node Address_node = root_node.child("Address");
xml_node Name_node = Address_node .child("Name");
xml_node Street_node = Address_node .child("Street");
xml_node City_node = Address_node .child("City");
xml_node Country_node = Address_node .child("Country");
```

Comment: Isn't extracting nodes in a loop "extracting them one by one"? Can you explain the difference between the two? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: @Borgleader: I have updated my question to clarify what do I mean by "extracting one by one". Kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for(auto node: doc.child("Employee").child("Address").children())
{
    std::cout << node.name() << ": " << node.text().as_string() << '\n';
}
```

Or for pre `C++11` compilers:

```
pugi::xml_object_range<pugi::xml_node_iterator> nodes = doc.child("Employee").child("Address").children();

for(pugi::xml_node_iterator node = nodes.begin(); node != nodes.end(); ++node)
{
    std::cout << node->name() << ": " << node->text().as_string() << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name: XYZ
Street: street no. 1
City: current city
Country: country
```

Comment: `for(auto node: doc.child("Employee").child("Address").children())` has syntax problem according to my IDE.

Comment: Are you using a compiler that supports C++11?

Comment: no...I replaced `auto` by `xml_node` but I don't know for the rest syntax

Comment: You need to use a regular for loop then. I wouldnt be surprised if `.childen()` returned a vector or some other container, so just grab a reference to that and do a regular for loop as you usually do. Or alternatively consider upgrading your compiler (if possible).

Comment: @skm I added an alternative syntax for old compilers.